# joomla, add modultes to the menu

Tags: joomla

i created new joomla module "hello world". And how make that, his show only i push on the menu, for example "Hello worl mod" link.

In short, how to add a module to the menu.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is going to take a custom menu module to do that. Yootheme's Warp framework has a menu module that does exactly what you need, you can get more info here -

http://www.yootheme.com/warp/